# How to find intersection points of linear and semi-logarithmic plots

Tags: equation-solving

Hopefully the title depicts what I am trying to do.

Below is a figure of my calculations that is shown in logarithmic scale in the x-axis. I am trying to find a way to find the intersection point at y = 0 (the purple line). It would be appreciative if I could get your input into how to find the intersection point, or how to work around it.

Here is my code:

```
ϵp = 2.6;
σp = 10000;

ϵm = 6;
σm = 0.01;

ϵp1[w_] := ϵp - (\[ImaginaryJ]*σp/w);

ϵm1[w_] := ϵm - (\[ImaginaryJ]*σm/w);

Figure = LogLinearPlot[{Re[(ϵp1[w] - ϵm1[
        w])/(ϵp1[w] + (2 ϵm1[w]))], 0}, {w, 0.01, 
   100000000000000000000000}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.01, 10000000000}, {-0.5, 1.3}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"ω [rad/s]", "Re[K(ω)]"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15]]

Export["Figure.png", Figure]

Solve[Re[(ϵp1[w] - ϵm1[w])/(ϵp1[
       w] + (2 ϵm1[w]))] == 0, w]
```

I have tried using Solve[] function, but I suspect that unless I change to semi-log data for w somehow, this method will not work.

Please let me know if you require additional information. Any comments or further discussion would be greatly appreciated.

Tat

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [ComplexExpand](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
ϵp = 26/10;
σp = 10000;

ϵm = 6;
σm = 1/100;

ϵp1[w_] := ϵp - (I*σp/w);

ϵm1[w_] := ϵm - (I*σm/w);

soln = w /. 
  Solve[{ComplexExpand[
        Re[(ϵp1[w] - ϵm1[w])/(ϵp1[
             w] + (2 ϵm1[w]))]] == 0 // Simplify, w > 0}, 
    w][[1]]

(*  (9*Sqrt[6172845679/2482])/10  *)

% // N

(*  1419.33  *)

Figure = LogLinearPlot[{Re[(ϵp1[w] - ϵm1[
        w])/(ϵp1[w] + (2 ϵm1[w]))], 0}, {w, 0.01, 
   100000000000000000000000}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.01, 10000000000}, {-0.5, 1.3}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"ω [rad/s]", "Re[K(ω)]"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], 
    Tooltip[Point[{Log[soln], 0}], {soln // N, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Bob. It helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've plotted it already, and know the approximate solution (around 1000), you can give that as a guess to `FindRoot`,

```
FindRoot[
 Re[(ϵp1[w] - ϵm1[w])/(ϵp1[
       w] + (2 ϵm1[w]))] == 0, {w, 1000}]
(* {w -> 1419.33} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, Jason. That's a nice way of doing it.